# super() в классах Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, классы

При знакомстве с фреймворком *PyQt5*, я заметил, что в функцию `super()` еще и записывают параметры.

Я не могу понять, зачем и почему, и что это дает?

Пример:

```
class Example(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Example, self).__init__()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*PyQt5* здесь ни при чем.

Один из способов, которым *Python* достигает парадигмы
объектно-ориентированную программирования,
этого — **`поддержка наследования`**, что он делает с помощью `super()`.

```
class Example(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
      super(Example, self).__init__()
```

В *Python 3* вызов `super(Example, self)` эквивалентен вызову `super()` без параметров.

`super()` может принимать два параметра:

- первый параметр является подклассом,
- а второй параметр является объектом,
  который является экземпляром этого подкласса.